# Git remove duplicate commits from history

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

So.... I say trying to remove a file from history as it contained a password (I know - should have been in gitignore from the start!).  I followed https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/ to point 6 but I had an issue with my SSH key being used by Git Bash (usually use sourcetree as store the repository on BitBucket) that had to be fixed and now I have a duplicate of all commits in my history (except the latest two).

The duplicate commits are independent when looking at the parents.  In effect it looks as though there are two branches of master that have never merged.

Here is a look at the top and bottom of my log:
[Top and bottom of log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfaQK.jpg)

If anyone can suggest how I can clean this up I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a comment by [agrias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5326358/agrias) asking

> Is "Pub-201603141450" a branch?

(It is a Tag)
I realised that all of my Tags were on the old commits.  Deleting these tags or moving them to the new version of the commit removed the old commits from my history.  Not being that familiar with tags I guess these hold their own history.

I guess if I hadn't had the SSH key issue and followed on with step 7 in https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/ it would have moved my tags over and avoided this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not a sourcetree user but you clean up your history with rebase.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~x
```

Where x is the # of commits you want to go back by.

If you want to just visually clean up your history and keep the commits you can use the `squash` option. If you want to remove the commits altogether you can just remove the commits by deleting the lines in your editor.

Comment: As the offending commits reach back to the first commit I can't use rebase (unless someone can suggest how I can) and I thought squash would squash a commit with its parent - which don't cross between the two branches shown. How do I delete selected commits?

Comment: Is "Pub-201603141450" a branch? If so how's the `git log` for it look. If it looks okay you can try changing the head of master to point to the head of  the good branch. From the appearance on source tree it looks like the yellow line is its own branch, the key here might be checking out that branch.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of commit is not so much, then creating a new branch and using `git cherry-pick` get commit you need one-by-one can be a solutions perhaps. Of cause you can write script to do it. After finished it, you can delete old branch you do not want.

By the way.

> I thought squash would squash a commit with its parent

This is not correct, `git rebase -i` provide several options, not only squashing a commit with its parent.